# Jump to specific point in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I've run into a bit of a brick wall with an app I'm working on and I just can't get my head around how to jump to a specific view controller in a navigation controllers stack.

So to give an overview of the structure of the app. I'm using Storyboards and Segues for navigation between views.

**Home Screen** - this pulls a list of the 4 latest job updates from the server and displays them in a table and has a button which displays the UINavigationController modally.

**UINavigationController**

**Job List** - pulls a list of all current jobs from the server and displays them in a table. On selecting a cell, `jobid` is set in Job details during `prepareForSegue:`, which is then pushed onto the stack.

**Job Details** - pulls all the details (description, photos etc.) of the job and displays them.

So navigating the jobs via the home screen button > Job List > Job Details isn't a problem and works perfectly.

What I can't figure out is how to jump to the details of a specific job when selecting one of the latest job updates on the Home Screen.

I hope I've explained it enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a couple of properties in your JobListViewController:

```
@property (assign) int initialisedWithSelectedJob;
@property (assign) int selectedJob;
```

When you present modally from homescreen, if a job is selected pass it to initialisedWithSelectedJob in JobListViewController:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender  {

   [(JobListViewController*)[segue.destinationViewController topViewController] 
                                     setInitialisedWithSelectedJob:selectedJob];

}
```

Then in your JobListViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
if (self.initialisedWithSelectedJob)
    {   
        self.selectedJob = initialisedWithSelectedJob;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"onToJobDetails" sender:self];
        self.initialisedWithSelectedJob == 0;
    }
```

You have to reset initialisedWithSelectedJob so that you can return here from the JobDetails screen without being bounced straight back again. ).

In your JobListViewController's prepareForSegue you can pass on the selectedJob id as you do already.

*update*

This way, you will return from Job Detail to JobListViewController. The movement from home screen -> job list screen -> job detail screen will be consistent regardless whether you select a job on home screen or list screen.

If you follow `0x7fffffff`'s answer then the navigation is quite different whether you select a job from the home screen or job list screen.

I am wondering whether you should rethink your design a little - having your job list on both the home screen and in JobListViewController is perhaps a little redundant?

Comment: That, is a great answer and worked perfectly while maintaining the stack order. Which I prefer to using `0x7fffffff`'s method which would require me to adjust things a fair bit. Thank you. I'm not sure having the latest job updates on the home view is redundant. This short list is quite different to the job list which could be displayed in a different order and displays different information about the job. But thanks for the thought, it was considered at design time.

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder you can assign an ID to the view controller that you wish to push to:

[image]

Then when the user selects the "latest job" you can use the following to push to the view controller with that identifier.

```
UIViewController *detailController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myID"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
```

Of course, in order to do this you'll have to embed your home view controller within a navigation controller as well.

Comment: Thanks for that, I prefer `He Was`'s method below as it maintains the current navigation stack. However I didn't know about using the Storyboard ID in that way so it was helpful.